# CSS border color switch animation: "from" color not correct

Tags: html, css, border, css-animations

I built a **css animation** and part of it is changing the **border color** of a div.

I'm using *from* and *to* values. The border should **blink white and blue** but instead of white I get a **light blue**.

I built a minimal snippet to demonstrate this. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```css
.switch {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 5px solid white;
  -webkit-animation: switch-animation 2s steps(2, start) infinite;
  animation: switch-animation 2s steps(2, start) infinite;
}

@keyframes switch-animation {
  from {
    border-color: white;
  }
  to {
    border-color: blue;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes switch-animation {
  from {
    border-color: white;
  }
  to {
    border-color: blue;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <div class="switch"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Imagine you're standing on one spot, and you want to be 2 steps away. Take a step. You're now at 50% of where you want to be. Take another step. You're now 100% away. `steps` works just like that. When you use `steps(2, start)` the two steps being used is 50%, and 100%. Use`steps(2, end)` and it will do the exact opposite. NicossB's solution is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work.

```css
.switch {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 5px solid white;
  -webkit-animation: switch-animation 2s steps(1, start) infinite;
  animation: switch-animation 2s steps(1, start) infinite;
}

@keyframes switch-animation {
  0%,100% {
    border-color: white;
  }
  50% {
    border-color: blue;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes switch-animation {
  0%,100%{
    border-color: white;
  }
  50% {
    border-color: blue;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <div class="switch"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6):

According to [the documenation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/single-transition-timing-function) `steps(2,start)` will give this timing output:

[image]

So you will spend `0` time on the first state, half the time on the `50%` (light blue) and half the time on the `100%` (blue). You will have a similar logic using `end` instead of `start` where you will spend `0` time on the last state. Actually what you are looking for is the `frames` function but it's actually under draft and using `frames(2)` you will do exactly what you want:

[image]

An easy fix is to change the values of the keyframes to force each color to stay half the animation without using `steps`

```css
.switch {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 5px solid white;
  animation: switch-animation 2s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes switch-animation {
  0%,50% {
    border-color: white;
  }
  50.1%,100% {
    border-color: blue;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="switch"></div>
```

Comment: nice answer with explanations. should be marked as answer.

Comment: Nice answer, appreciate the detail.