# Match color for animating cursor and span inside

Tags: css, css-animations

I'm using prism to display tokens and on top if it I have cursor that animate blinking, the problem is color of the token is set to almost the same color as background of the cursor:

Here is minimal example:

```css
@keyframes terminal-blink {
  0%, 100% {
      background-color: var(--background, #000);
      color: var(--color, #aaa);
      border-bottom: none;
      border-left: none;
      margin-left: 0;
  }
  50% {
      background-color: var(--color, #aaa);
      color: var(--background, #000);
      border-bottom: none;
      border-left: none;
      margin-left: 0;
  }
}

.cursor.blink {
    -webkit-animation: terminal-blink 1s infinite steps(1, start);
       -moz-animation: terminal-blink 1s infinite steps(1, start);
        -ms-animation: terminal-blink 1s infinite steps(1, start);
            animation: terminal-blink 1s infinite steps(1, start);
}
body {
   background: black;
   font-family: monospace;
}
.token.punctuation {
    color: #999;
}
.token.tag {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="cursor blink">
     <span style="font-weight:bold;" class="token punctuation" data-text="<">&lt;</span>
  </span>
</div>
<br/>
<div>
  <span class="cursor blink">
     <span style="font-weight:bold;" class="" data-text="x">x</span>
  </span>
</div>

<div>
  <span class="cursor blink">
     <span style="font-weight:bold;" class="token tag" data-text="x">x</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

I've tried to set another animation that will overwrite .token.punctuation  using:

```
 @keyframes prism-cursor {
     0%, 100% {
         color: currentColor;
     }
     50% {
         color: #000;
     }
 }
 .cursor .token {
     animation: prism-cursor 1s infinite steps(1, start);
 }
```

but it don't work and it's out of sync, it look like there are 3 steps animation.

I want to have `color: var(--color)` when cursor is visible (animation is at 50%) but be color from .token when cursor is invisible 0%, 100%. (`.token.tag` should be red on black background and black on gray).

Here is example of actual Code I have https://codepen.io/jcubic/pen/MqyvEG

Is something like this possible without modifying `.token` css nor html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended up with this code. First I've added another span inside the one that have background and applied this code:

```
.cmd span[data-text] span {
    background: inherit;
    color: inherit;
}
.cmd .cursor.blink > span[style*="background"] span {
    animation: terminal-blink-span 1s infinite steps(1, start);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
.cmd .cursor.blink > span[style*="background"] {
    postion: relative;
    min-width: 1ch;
    display: inline-block;
}
/*
 * I've created another css var here, because
 * I've added --color to span and I've needed to
 * have a way to select original color as backgound
 * for cursor animation
 */
.cmd {
    --original-color: var(--color, #aaa);
}
@keyframes terminal-blink-span {
    0%, 100% {
        background: inherit;
        color: inherit;
    }
    50% {
        background: var(--original-color, #aaa);
        color: var(--background, #000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First I would suggest considering something else than `steps`. As I explained in another question ([CSS border color switch animation: "from" color not correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51842908/css-border-color-switch-animation-from-color-not-correct/51843473#51843473)) it may lead to confusion on how it works.

Considering this you can easily apply a second animation without synchronization issue:

```css
@keyframes terminal-blink {
  0%,
  50% {
    background-color: var(--background, #000);
    color: var(--color, #aaa);
    border-bottom: none;
    border-left: none;
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  50.1%,
  100% {
    background-color: var(--color, #aaa);
    color: var(--background, #000);
    border-bottom: none;
    border-left: none;
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes prism-cursor {
  0%,
  50% {
    color: var(--c,white);
  }
  50.1%,
  100% {
    color: #000;
  }
}

.cursor.blink {
  animation: terminal-blink 1s infinite linear;
}

body {
  background: black;
  font-family: monospace;
}

.token.punctuation {
  --c:red;
  color: var(--c);
  animation: prism-cursor 1s infinite linear;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="cursor blink">
     <span style="font-weight:bold;" class="token punctuation" data-text="<">&lt;</span>
  </span>
</div>
<br>
<div>
  <span class="cursor blink">
     <span style="font-weight:bold;" class="" data-text="x">x</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

And you can reduce the code to only one animation if you move all the classes at the same level:

```css
@keyframes terminal-blink {
  0%,
  50% {
    background-color: var(--background, #000);
    color: var(--c, #aaa);
    border-bottom: none;
    border-left: none;
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  50.1%,
  100% {
    background-color: var(--color, #aaa);
    color: var(--background, #000);
    border-bottom: none;
    border-left: none;
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}

.cursor.blink {
  animation: terminal-blink 1s infinite linear;
}

body {
  background: black;
  font-family: monospace;
}

.token {
  --c:red;
  color: var(--c);
}
.punctuation {
  --c:green;
  color: var(--c);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="cursor blink token ">
     <span style="font-weight:bold;" data-text="<">&lt;</span>
  </span>
</div>
<br>
<div>
  <span class="cursor blink punctuation">
     <span style="font-weight:bold;" class="" data-text="x">x</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: @jcubic --c is defined in the class :) so it will take it from there ;) and if nothing is defined it will be white ... check my update I have added anothe example

Comment: I didn't notice the scrollbar, so it seems that without --c is not possible, I wanted to use [prismjs](https://prismjs.com/) css without modification.

Comment: @jcubic what things you cannot update? I don't know how prismjs works

Comment: .token and .punctuation came from prismjs and I'm injecting it into .cursor, I would like to not modify cursor class based on prism output because I would need to parse output of prism and modify the DOM to update. Here is example of what I have https://codepen.io/jcubic/pen/MqyvEG

Comment: I'm marking your solution, since it almost solve my problem, the only issue is that I need to modify `.token` classes.

Comment: @jcubic ok got it, will update in case I find a workaround

Comment: I've decided to use different solution that require from me to only add span inside span that have color and/or background, I've added my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can create another keyframe that matches the timing of the first one and does the color change in sync.

```css
@keyframes terminal-blink {
  0%, 100% {
  background-color: var(--background, #000);
  color: var(--color, #aaa);
  border-bottom: none;
  border-left: none;
  margin-left: 0;
  }
  50% {
  background-color: var(--color, #aaa);
  color: var(--background, #000);
  border-bottom: none;
  border-left: none;
  margin-left: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes textHighlight {

  0%, 100% {
color: red;
  }
  50% {
color: blue;
  }
}

.cursor.blink {
-webkit-animation: terminal-blink 1s infinite steps(1, start);
   -moz-animation: terminal-blink 1s infinite steps(1, start);
    -ms-animation: terminal-blink 1s infinite steps(1, start);
        animation: terminal-blink 1s infinite steps(1, start);
}
.token {
-webkit-animation: textHighlight 1s infinite steps(1, start);
   -moz-animation: textHighlight 1s infinite steps(1, start);
    -ms-animation: textHighlight 1s infinite steps(1, start);
        animation: textHighlight 1s infinite steps(1, start);
}
body {
   background: black;
   font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="cursor blink">
     <span style="font-weight:bold;" class="token" data-text="<">&lt;</span>
  </span>
</div>
<br/>
<div>
  <span class="cursor blink">
     <span style="font-weight:bold;" class="token" data-text="x">x</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: This will not work because I want to have color: var(--color) when cursor is visible (animation is at 50%) but be color from .token when cursor is invisible 0%, 100%.

Comment: The problem Is that I have colors in `.token` and I want it to be in animation preferably without modification to `.token` class.