# Responsive Circle with CSS Sprite background

Tags: html, css, background-image, css-sprites

I'm having issues knowing how to do the right math or formula to make a responsive css sprite.
Its a circle with border radius 50%. So its width and padding-bottom are set to 100% to make the circle proportionate.

My issue is getting the sprite to match up and step(16 times) through the animation and work responsively. I can get it work static with px.

```css
.hero_sprite_container {
  width: 100%;
}

.hero_sprite {
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: green url('https://i.imgur.com/F1wpeSB.jpg') no-repeat 0 0;
  background-size: 100%;
  animation: sprite 10s steps(16) infinite;
}

@keyframes sprite {
  to {
    background-position: 0 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="hero_image">
  <div class="hero_sprite_container">
    <div class="hero_sprite lazyload"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my code pen so you can see it.

https://codepen.io/gorelegacy/pen/ExxXZge

my sprite - https://i.imgur.com/F1wpeSB.jpg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is related to the use of `background-position` with percentage value which will not give you the intended result using 16 steps. Instead you can use a pseudo element as background layer and consider translatation:

```css
.hero_sprite {
  width: 50%; 
  margin:auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;
  z-index:0;
}
/*To maintain the ratio*/
.hero_sprite:before {
   content:"";
   display:inline-block;
   padding-bottom: 100%;
}
/* the background layer */
.hero_sprite:after {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  height:1600%; /* N * 100% */
  background:url('https://i.imgur.com/F1wpeSB.jpg')top/100% 100%;
  animation: sprite 10s steps(16) infinite; /* Steps(N) */
}

@keyframes sprite {
  to {
    transform: translateY(-100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="hero_sprite lazyload"></div>
```

With background, you either need to use pixel values (not scalable)

```css
.hero_sprite_container {
  width: 100%;
}

.hero_sprite {
  width: 200px;
  height:200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: green url('https://i.imgur.com/F1wpeSB.jpg') no-repeat 0 0;
  background-size: 100% auto;
  animation: sprite 10s steps(16) infinite;
}

@keyframes sprite {
  to {
    background-position: 0 -3200px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="hero_image">
  <div class="hero_sprite_container">
    <div class="hero_sprite lazyload"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or define `15` in the steps but you will miss one image:

```css
.hero_sprite_container {
  width: 100%;
}

.hero_sprite {
  width: 50%;
  padding-top:50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: green url('https://i.imgur.com/F1wpeSB.jpg') no-repeat 0 0;
  background-size: 100% auto;
  animation: sprite 10s steps(15) infinite;
}

@keyframes sprite {
  to {background-position: 0 100%;}
}
```

```html
<div class="hero_image">
  <div class="hero_sprite_container">
    <div class="hero_sprite lazyload"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can rectify the below issue by adding an empty slot at end then define 16 steps.

Related to understand how `steps` works https://stackoverflow.com/a/51843473/8620333

You can also manually define the different position but it would be tedious:

```css
.hero_sprite_container {
  width: 100%;
}

.hero_sprite {
  width: 50%;
  padding-top:50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: green url('https://i.imgur.com/F1wpeSB.jpg') no-repeat 0 0;
  background-size: 100% auto;
  animation: sprite 10s  infinite;
}

@keyframes sprite {
  0%     , 6.25%  {background-position: 0 calc(0*100%/15);}
  6.26%  , 12.5%  {background-position: 0 calc(1*100%/15);}
  12.51% , 18.75% {background-position: 0 calc(2*100%/15);}
  18.76% , 25%    {background-position: 0 calc(3*100%/15);}
  25.01% , 31.25% {background-position: 0 calc(4*100%/15);}
  31.26% , 37.5%  {background-position: 0 calc(5*100%/15);}
  37.51% , 43.75% {background-position: 0 calc(6*100%/15);}
  43.76% , 50%    {background-position: 0 calc(7*100%/15);}
  50.01% , 56.25% {background-position: 0 calc(8*100%/15);}
  56.26% , 62.5%  {background-position: 0 calc(9*100%/15);}
  62.51% , 68.75% {background-position: 0 calc(10*100%/15);}
  68.76% , 75%    {background-position: 0 calc(11*100%/15);}
  75.01% , 81.25% {background-position: 0 calc(12*100%/15);}
  81.26% , 87.5%  {background-position: 0 calc(13*100%/15);}
  87.51% , 93.75% {background-position: 0 calc(14*100%/15);}
  93.76% , 100%   {background-position: 0 calc(15*100%/15);}
}
```

```html
<div class="hero_image">
  <div class="hero_sprite_container">
    <div class="hero_sprite lazyload"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for the help! great work.
i couldn't find many examples like this online so i appreciate it